# Host php and nodejs on same azure web app

Tags: php, azure

I want to host a nodejs and php on same azure web app. I have successfully hosted the nodejs app and it works. While i tried to use web.config to ignore the sub folder where the php files are.

First i tried this

```
 <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="phpbb/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />

          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js"/>
        </rule>
```

And then this (copying the rule for public folders)

```
<!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>
```

But nothing seems to work. I'd appreciate any help i can get please.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could check this video:[Making multi-language Azure Web Sites with PHP, node.js, .NET and more](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/multi-language-azure-web-sites-with-php-node-and-dotnet/).

Note: Web app is similar with web site. Web app is a Arm mode resource. Web site is classic mode.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance. –